How to Avoid Duplicated Text in Custom Label References with enumitem in LaTeX?
I am currently trying to use enumitem to create custom reference labels in my document. I have defined global commands for the enumerators, as follows:
% File: enumitem-config.tex
\newcommand
    {\SectionName}
    {Terms}


\newcommand
    {\FirstLevelEnumerator}
    {{\SectionName} {\S} \theenumi}


\newcommand
    {\SecondLevelEnumerator}
    {{\FirstLevelEnumerator}(\theenumii)}


\newcommand
    {\ThirdLevelEnumerator}
    {{\SecondLevelEnumerator}--\theenumiii}



% File: main.tex
\import{path/to}{enumitem-config.tex}

...

\begin{enumerate}[ref = \FirstLevelEnumerator]
   \item\label{reference:one} Item 1
   \begin{enumerate}[ref = \SecondLevelEnumerator]
      \item\label{reference:one-a} Item 1(a)
      \begin{enumerate}[ref = \ThirdLevelEnumerator]
         \item\label{reference:one-a-i} Item 1(a)-i
      \end{enumerate}
   \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

...

However, when I use the following commands within the list, I encounter these results:
Terms § 1
Terms § Terms § 1(a)
Terms § Terms § 1(Terms § Terms § 1(a))–i

What I want to receive:
Terms § 1
Terms § 1(a)
Terms § 1(a)–i

It seems that the variables are being expanded multiple times because when I omit the ref parameter in the parent list, the duplication partially disappears.
Main Question:
How can I avoid this or alter the behavior to achieve the desired result?

Welcome. // Why do you think your code will compile, once we copied and try it ?? Please add, what's missing for this purpose. Thank you

Welcome to TeX.SE! please make your given code snippet be compilable! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

You just have to be a little more explicit in your new label commands to avoid that expansion.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\SectionName}{Terms\ \S}

\newcommand{\FirstLevelEnumerator}{\SectionName\ \theenumi}
\newcommand{\SecondLevelEnumerator}{\theenumi(\theenumii)}
\newcommand{\ThirdLevelEnumerator}{\theenumii--\theenumiii}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[ref=\FirstLevelEnumerator]
   \item\label{reference:one} Item 1 REF: \ref{reference:one}
   \begin{enumerate}[ref=\SecondLevelEnumerator]
      \item\label{reference:one-a} Item 1(a) REF: \ref{reference:one-a}
      \begin{enumerate}[ref=\ThirdLevelEnumerator]
         \item\label{reference:one-a-i} Item 1(a)-i REF: \ref{reference:one-a-i}
      \end{enumerate}
   \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}



Thanks for the solution! After your example, I realized that \theenumii inside of \ThirdLevelEnumerator are basically "re-inserting" the labels of the parent lists! Now it make sense!
